# Problem with node-gyp not using the npm configured private registry

Tags: node.js, npm, configuration, node-gyp

The server this is running on is behind a corporate firewall, and only has access out to this specific private registry, which also acts as a proxy out to the public npm registry (for packages that we don't have).

NPM itself is working fine; but when the node-gyp module is used, it tries to do a GET out to nodejs.org - `gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v9.11.2/node-v9.11.2-headers.tar.gz`. That fails, because the system doesn't have access to reach that. Question is why isn't node-gyp using the registry that was defined in the npm config? Or do I have to setup a separate config for the headers to use a separate source?

Here is my npm config settings:

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://corporate/registry/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.6.0 node/v9.11.2 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/user123/.npmrc
always-auth = true
cafile = "/home/user123/pub-cert.crt"
registry = "https://corporate/registry/"
sass_binary_path = "/root/linux-x64-59_binding.node"
strict-ssl = false
```

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution ?

Comment: Hi, @xil3. Do you have any news about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the node-gyp [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp), I was able to eventually get it working for my situation by doing the following before performing a node build:

```
npm config set disturl <url>
```

(in your case, `<url>` would be `https://corporate/registry/`, assuming that is the root url of your private npm registry.
In your `.npmrc`, that would likely look like:

```
disturl = "https://corporate/registry/"
```

---

I originally tried doing the equivalent via setting an environment variable, but the frustrating part is that the node-gyp docs linked above specifically say

> Use the form npm_config_OPTION_NAME for any of the command options listed above (dashes in option names should be replaced by underscores)

Given that their docs refer to the corresponding flag as `--dist-url`, you would assume the env var would be `npm_config_dist_url`, but that is wrong. It's actually `npm_config_disturl`.

---

With either of the above approaches, however, you will need to assure your registry also contains the `SHASUM256.txt` file which can be obtained via the following command: `curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/vx.y.z/SHASUMS256.txt`, replacing `x.y.z` with the version in question, in your case `9.11.2`.

A third option would be to download the headers tgz from your private registry ahead of time using `wget` or a similar tool, then setting the `tarball` setting with `npm config set tarball <path/to/downloaded/headers.tgz>` (or the `.npmrc`/env var equivalent approaches). This method does not enforce verifying checksums.